# Select products which not ordered or do not have order with success status

Tags: mysql

Given a products and an orders table.
I would like to get products which never ordered or ordered but order status was not success ever.

To get products never ordered I use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN orders o ON p.product_id=o.product_id
WHERE order_id IS NULL
GROUP BY p.product_id;
```

I think this query is OK.

To get products never ordered OR ordered but order_status is failed or interrupted I use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN orders o ON p.product_id=o.product_id
WHERE (order_id IS NULL OR (order_id>0 AND (order_status=5 OR order_status=9))
GROUP BY p.product_id;
```

It does not give what I want, because if a product is ordered two times and one time the order is success (order_status is 4) and one time order is failed (order_status is 5) the given product will be in the result. But I need products which never has a success order.

Comment: What are possible values for `order_status`? Couldn't you just say "Products that don't have order_status=4"?

Answer (score 0):

you should move the condition for columns related  to eft joined tables  in ON clause

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN orders o ON p.product_id=o.product_id 
      AND (order_id IS NULL OR (order_id>0 AND (order_status=5 OR order_status=9))
```

the use of where for column related to left joined  table work as an inner  join (and don't produce result for these rows)

and you should not use group by without aggregation function, this produce unpredictable result for mysql version < 5.7 and is not allowed  by default for mysql version>= 5.7

use distinct or add proper aggregation function for column not invoved  in group by clause

```
SELECT p.product_id, max(col1), max(col2) ..... 
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN orders o ON p.product_id=o.product_id 
      AND (order_id IS NULL OR (order_id>0 AND (order_status=5 OR order_status=9))
GROUP BY p.product_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
WHERE p.product_id NOT IN (
     --This query returns all successfull orders
     select product_id from orders where order_id > 0 and order_status = 4
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the logic of your first query and add an additional condition in the ON clause:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN orders o
  ON  o.product_id   = p.product_id
  AND o.order_status = 4
WHERE order_id IS NULL
```

Note that you don't need `GROUP BY` here, since you will only get one row per product either way (assuming that orders.order_id is primary key).

That query is equivalent to

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM orders o
    WHERE o.product_id   = p.product_id
      AND o.order_status = 4
)
```

And this can be read as "Select all products that don't have orders with status = 4 (success)".

If your logic is rather "Select all products that don't have any orders or have only orders with status 5 or 9" - Then you can use

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN orders o
  ON  o.product_id   = p.product_id
  AND o.order_status NOT IN (5, 9)
WHERE order_id IS NULL
```